# Assigning dates to predictions generated via HoltWinters in R

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, xts, prediction

I'm interested in making use of the [`HoltWinters`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/HoltWinters.html) function in r to obtain a simple [timeserieschart](/questions/tagged/timeserieschart) with the x-axis values corresponding to the future dates. The situation is illustrated with use of the following example:

## Example

### Data

I have a simple time series, of the following nature:

```
dta <- airquality
dta$date <- as.Date(paste(dta$Day, dta$Month, 2002), format = "%d%m%Y")
dta <- dta[,c("Ozone", "date")]
rownames(dta) <- dta$date
dta$date <- NULL
```

*`airquality` corresponds to `data(airquality)`*

### `ts` object

The actual frequency is arbitrary; set just for the purpose of example.

```
dta <- dta[, 1]
dta <- na.omit(dta)
dta <- ts(data = dta, frequency = 7)
holtFits <- HoltWinters(x = dta)
```

### Prediction

```
  holtPredicts <- predict(
    object = holtFits,
    n.ahead = 200,
    level = 0.8,
    prediction.interval = TRUE
  )
```

### Problem

The problem relates to plotting the obtained predictions ***with*** the actual data on a single chart with x axis showing dates. I can obtained the desired object using [zoo](/questions/tagged/zoo), [lubridate](/questions/tagged/lubridate) and [xts](/questions/tagged/xts) packages:

```
require(zoo); require(xts); require(lubridate)
dtaTimeMrgd <-
  merge(actual = as.zoo(dta),
        predicted = as.zoo(holtPredicts))
dtaTimeMrgd <-  xts(dtaTimeMrgd,
                    order.by = date_decimal(index(dtaTimeMrgd)))
```

The derived are not usable:

```
>> head(dtaTimeMrgd)
                    actual fit upr lwr
0001-01-01 00:00:00     41  NA  NA  NA
0001-02-22 03:25:43     36  NA  NA  NA
0001-04-15 06:51:26     12  NA  NA  NA
0001-06-06 10:17:09     18  NA  NA  NA
0001-07-28 13:42:52     28  NA  NA  NA
0001-09-18 17:08:35     23  NA  NA  NA
```

However, the plot would show correctly. Example with use of `dygraphs`:

```
require(dygraphs)
dygraph(dtaTimeMrgd) %>% dyAxis(name = "x", label = "dates" )
```

[image: plot with predictions]

#### Approaches

I'm interested in arriving at a correct date in the obtained `dtaTimeMrg` object with the past dates corresponding to the previously provided dates and new dates reflecting date corresponding to the period estimated via the `predict` function.  A sample approach could involve adding days and years from the :

```
index(dtaTimeMrgd) + years(2002)
```

However, this is not robust for a data set that spans across multiple years and has gaps. The new dates would also have to account for the frequency of time series object.